# Python: How to move file from directory to another based on items in the separate list?

Tags: python

I have a list of names mentioned below. Also there are .csv files with the same names in the directory. I want to move .csv files from one directory to another based names mentioned in the list. But its not working. Please suggest.

```
list = ['john','jenny','mike']
csv files in source dir are john.csv, jenny.csv, mike.csv
destination dir = ('c:\\users\\dest\\')

for files in list:
   if not os.path.exists("c:\\dest\\"):
       os.makedirs("n:\\users\\dest\\")
       shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
list = ['john','jenny','mike']
destination = 'c:\\users\\dest\\'
for file in list:
    shutil.move("your_source_path"+"\"+file+".csv", destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never change the value of the `source` variable, so it's always set to the same filename (assuming you did set it correctly - it's never set anywhere in your example). What you need to do is loop through the names in the list, append '.csv' to each of the names, and move that file:

```
import os
import shutil


l = ['john', 'jenny', 'mike']
if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\Dest'):
    os.mkdir('C:\\Users\Dest')

for name in l:
    shutil.move(f'{your_source_dir}\\{name}.csv', 'C:\\Users\Dest')
```